# Check if all elements from one array are in the second array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I check if all the elements from one array are in another array? I have a 2d array with 3 arrays in it,and I want to check all of those 3 arrays if they have all the elements from allnumbers. array1=allnumbers ? array2=allnumbers ? array1=allnumber2 ? I need to return true if at least one contains all the elements from allnumbers. I have the code bellow,but I need it not to contain more than 3 control flow statements.

```
// int[,][] array = {array1, array2, array3}
static bool CheckLine(int[,][] array)
        {
            const int maxL = 9;
            bool result = false;
            int[] allnumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            foreach (var singlearray in array)
            {
                int[] arr = singlearray;
                int p = 0;
                foreach (var num in allnumbers)
                {
                    foreach (var arraynumber in singlearray)
                    {
                        if (arraynumber == num)
                        {
                            p++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (p == maxL)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Except` method? Please, also share the `int[,][] array` sample

Answer (score 2):

If the values in your array are unique, and you don't care about the order they're in, this is a job for [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8).  (In other words, if your arrays contain sets of numbers you can treat them as sets.) Here's the basic outline of comparing sets.

```
var allnumbersSet = new HashSet<int>(allnumbers);
var allnumbers2Set= new HashSet<int>(allnumbers2);

if (allnumbersSet.IsSupersetOf(allnumbers2Set)) {
   /* everything in allnumbers2 is also in allnumbers1 */
}
```

The people who put together DotNet did a really good job creating and optimizing those collection classes; you can use them with confidence to get good performance.

Comment: I think it's better to leave allnumbers2 as is since it's unnecessary for argument of IsSupersetOf to be HashSet.

Comment: So basically you want some kind of ienumerable to just walk through and hashset to check if it's there

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you have two-dimensional [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). You can simplify your code by using [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) and check the difference between `allnumbers` array and single row at every loop iteration.

```cs
static bool CheckLine(int[,][] array)
{
    int[] allnumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    foreach (var singlearray in array)
    {
        var diff = allnumbers.Except(singlearray);
        if (!diff.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If there is no elements in a difference, it'll mean that single item from source 2D array has all elements from `allnumbers` array.

Example of the usage

```cs
var array = new int[2, 2][];
array[0, 0] = new[] { 1, 2, 8 };
array[0, 1] = new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
array[1, 1] = new[] { 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8 };
array[1, 0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

CheckLine(array);
```

The last two items satisfy the condition, execution will break and return `true` for `{ 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8 }` array. Also don't forget to add `using System.Linq` directive at the top of file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I forgot to mention that I can use only "using System;"

Comment: I guess, it should be a comment, not the answer. You can add `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Collections.Generic` to make the answers above working

Comment: I saw it`s working with using System.Linq; , but I`m not allowed to use it. I need to use only "using System;"